# C# LINQ threw this error. how can I fix it?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Code throws this exception - how can I solve it?

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression:
> KeySelector: (Nullable)d.DiseasesCategoryId,
> ElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression:
> EntityType: Diagnosis
> ValueBufferExpression:
> ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
> IsNullable: False
> .GroupBy(p => p.Patient.Gender)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Code:

```
IQueryable<Diagnosis> diagnoses = _context.Diagnosis
    .Include(d => d.Patient)
    .Include(d => d.Prescription);
IQueryable<Diagnosis> diagnosesWithSpecification = diagnoses
    .Where(d => d.Prescription.UpdatedOn.Year == year && 
                d.Prescription.UpdatedOn.Month == month && 
                d.Prescription.HospitalId == hospitalId);

int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Date.Year;
var groupByDiseases = await diagnosesWithSpecification
    .GroupBy(dCat => dCat.DiseasesCategoryId)
    .Select(x => new
    {
       DiseasesCategoryId = x.Key,
       Gender = x.GroupBy(p => p.Patient.Gender).Select(y => new
       {
           Gender = y.Key,
           ZeroToFive = y.Count(p => (currentYear - p.Patient.DoB.Value.Date.Year) >= 0 && (currentYear - p.Patient.DoB.Value.Date.Year) <= 5),
           SixToFifteen = y.Count(p => (currentYear - p.Patient.DoB.Value.Date.Year) >= 6 && (currentYear - p.Patient.DoB.Value.Date.Year) <= 15),
           SixteenToThirty = y.Count(p => (currentYear - p.Patient.DoB.Value.Date.Year) >= 16 && (currentYear - p.Patient.DoB.Value.Date.Year) <= 30),
           ThirtyOneToFourtyFive = y.Count(p => (currentYear - p.Patient.DoB.Value.Date.Year) >= 31 && (currentYear - p.Patient.DoB.Value.Date.Year) <= 45),
           FourtySixToSixty = y.Count(p => (currentYear - p.Patient.DoB.Value.Date.Year) >= 46 && (currentYear - p.Patient.DoB.Value.Date.Year) <= 60),
           SixtyOnePlus = y.Count(p => (currentYear - p.Patient.DoB.Value.Date.Year) > 60),
           Total = y.Count()
       }).ToList(),
       TotalPatient = x.Count()
    }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Which version of EF Core do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.ToList()` before call none databse functions.

`diagnosesWithSpecification.ToList().GroupBy(dCat => dCat.DiseasesCategoryId)`...

Answer (score 1):

You need grouping on client side. Before that it is needed to simplify returned result set.

```cs
var data = await _context.Diagnosis
    .Where(d => d.Prescription.UpdatedOn.Year == year && 
                d.Prescription.UpdatedOn.Month == month && 
                d.Prescription.HospitalId == hospitalId)
    .Select(d = new 
    { 
        d.DiseasesCategoryId,
        d.Patient.Gender,
        p.Patient.DoB
     })
     .ToListAsync();

int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Date.Year;

var groupByDiseases = data
    .GroupBy(dCat => dCat.DiseasesCategoryId)
    .Select(x => new
    {
       DiseasesCategoryId = x.Key,
       Gender = x.GroupBy(p => p.Gender).Select(y => new
       {
           Gender = y.Key,
           ZeroToFive = y.Count(p => (currentYear - p.DoB.Value.Date.Year) >= 0 && (currentYear - p.DoB.Value.Date.Year) <= 5),
           SixToFifteen = y.Count(p => (currentYear - p.DoB.Value.Date.Year) >= 6 && (currentYear - p.DoB.Value.Date.Year) <= 15),
           SixteenToThirty = y.Count(p => (currentYear - p.DoB.Value.Date.Year) >= 16 && (currentYear - p.DoB.Value.Date.Year) <= 30),
           ThirtyOneToFourtyFive = y.Count(p => (currentYear - p.DoB.Value.Date.Year) >= 31 && (currentYear - p.DoB.Value.Date.Year) <= 45),
           FourtySixToSixty = y.Count(p => (currentYear - p.DoB.Value.Date.Year) >= 46 && (currentYear - p.DoB.Value.Date.Year) <= 60),
           SixtyOnePlus = y.Count(p => (currentYear - p.DoB.Value.Date.Year) > 60),
           Total = y.Count()
       }).ToList(),
       TotalPatient = x.Count()
    }).ToList();
```